# Get only last vale of dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am new in iOS development and my problem is when i parse data than only last value is showing above value are not showing .Please solve my issue.
Array name city info get 3 value but when i want to display them it gives onle last value of array.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:WebData1 options:0 error:0];
    NSArray *city_info = [json objectForKey:@"city_info"];
    for(NSDictionary *dic in city_info) {
        NSMutableArray *vlcc_service_name = [dic objectForKey:@"vlcc_service_name"];

        Centers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:vlcc_service_name, nil];
    }
    // NSLog(@"%@", vlcc_service_name);
    NSLog(@"%@", Centers);
    [_CenterTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: pleas give you json value of "city_info" to clarify

Comment: json data 
city_info
0
vlcc_service_name : "WEIGHT LOSS"
1
vlcc_service_name : "BEAUTY SALON"
2
vlcc_service_name : "GYM"

Comment: this is very simple. but you did not provide proper info to solve you issue.

Comment: please give the value of NSLog(@"%@", city_info);

Comment: which value do you need? from your  "city_info" array

Comment: I want to show  vlcc service name  in my table.

Comment: <__NSCFArray 0x78edffd0>(
{
    "vlcc_service_name" = "WEIGHT LOSS";
},
{
    "vlcc_service_name" = "BEAUTY SALON";
},
{
    "vlcc_service_name" = GYM;
}

Comment: that's fine. give you city_info please

Comment: value __NSCFString * @"WEIGHT LOSS" 0x78e38d00
value __NSCFString * @"BEAUTY SALON" 0x78e2c2d0
value __NSCFString * @"GYM" 0x78e50a00

Comment: City info an array and vlcc_service_name is dic..

Comment: do you want to show "WEIGHT LOSS", "BEAUTY SALON"  and "GYM" in tableview

Comment: yeah .How can i chat with you because stack over flow not allows me to chat .My reputation only 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:WebData1 options:0 error:0];
    NSArray *city_info = [json objectForKey:@"city_info"];
    NSMutableArray  *Centers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  for(NSDictionary *dic in city_info) {
    NSString *vlcc_service_name = [dic objectForKey:@"vlcc_service_name"];
   /NSLog(@"%@", vlcc_service_name);
    [Centers addObject: vlcc_service_name];
  }

NSLog(@"%@", Centers);
[_CenterTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: this i write code. but not tested. if it will not solve your problem then please  provide me the url

Comment: @jami65able -yeah its working .Thanks a lot but it shows data only in nslog  not in table view .Help

Comment: -Could you send me your mail id.

Comment: jmlhossain65@gmail.com

Comment: send table view method "cellforrow..." and "numberof row..." method

Comment: or, check first with static data to show in tableview

Comment: Static data are showing .

Comment: then please send cellforrowatindexpath method only

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    
    cell.textLabel.text = [Centers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

Comment: give me the NSLog of "[Centers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]"

Comment: if you get empty value then cut this NSMutableArray  *Centers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; line and paste it in viewdidload method

Comment: Still it is not showing data.

Comment: give me the NSLog of "[Centers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]"  from  "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method

Comment: it shows nothing.Also i edit nsmutable array in did load method

Comment: yes, here is the problem.

Comment: show me how many times and where you use "Centers"

Comment: I sent you .h and .m file on your mail id. please check this.

Comment: i sent you a mail. it works . i tested

Comment: Omg, what language are you two using? How do you understand each other?

Comment: programming ? or verbal?

Comment: Thanks sir it all works ....

Comment: @jamil65able, Verbal, I tried following the conversation to understand the problem and try to help but I couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

NSDictionaries are unordered,that there are not first or last element. In fact, the order of the keys are never guaranteed to be the same, even in the lifetime of a specific dictionary.

If you want any object, you can get one of the keys:

```
id key = [[json allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]; // ensure that your 'json' is not empty
id object = [json objectForKey:key];
```

**Choice - 2**

array you can get all objects

```
 Centers = [NSMutableArray new]; // allocate the memory on outside the Loop
for(NSDictionary *dic in city_info) {

    [Centers addObject: [dic objectForKey:@"vlcc_service_name"]];
}

 NSLog(@"the last object=%@", [Centers lastObject]);
// else
  NSLog(@"the last object=%@", [yourArray objectAtIndex:[Centers count] - 1]; );
```

Comment: sir .I understood your theory but your code i didn't get ..Please give me other logic to do this. Thanks

Comment: @HarshRajput -- check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:WebData1 options:0 error:0];
    NSArray *city_info = [json objectForKey:@"city_info"];
    NSMutableArray *Centers = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSDictionary *dic in city_info) {
        NSMutableArray *vlcc_service_name = [dic objectForKey:@"vlcc_service_name"];

        [Centers addObjectsFromArray:vlcc_service_name];
    }

    // NSLog(@"%@", vlcc_service_name);
    NSLog(@"%@", Centers);

    [_CenterTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @lulian it shows exception:- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @HarshRajput, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ lulian  it also gives exception:-reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray'

Comment: Then your `vlcc_service_name` variable that you are declaring as an `array` is not an ... array. Please update your question and add a sample JSON for which you are trying to run this code.

Comment: @HarshRajput, please use the reply field for questions. You can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) to share code.

Comment: @lulian -Thanks .i sent code on pastern and also thanks

Comment: @lulian how i can see answer in pastebin

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any `for loop`. Do like this: 
`NSMutableArray *Centers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initwithArray:city_info];`